# What is the shutdown command?

Tags: unity, launcher, shutdown, .desktop

I want to create a shutdown icon for the launcher in 13.04. In former versions of Ubuntu I used this desktop file and put it in the launcher:

.local/share/applications/**indicator-session-shutdown.desktop**

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Shut Down
TryExec=/usr/lib/indicator-session/gtk-logout-helper
Exec=/usr/lib/indicator-session/gtk-logout-helper --shutdown
Icon=system-shutdown
Terminal=false
Type=Application
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
Categories=System;
Version=1.0
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=indicator-session
```

I wonder if

```
/usr/lib/indicator-session/gtk-logout-helper --shutdown
```

is still the correct command in 13.04.

Here is a screenshot with old shutdown dialog:

[image]

Here is a screenshot with new shutdown dialog:

[image]

Comment: Does it work or not? You should try to know..

Comment: Yes it works but it shows the 'old' shutdown dialog. I would prefer the 'new' Unity 13.04 shutdown dialog.

Comment: To be more precise, it first shows the old dialog and then the new one. I'd like to call the new dialog immediatelly too avoid unnecessary mouse clicks.

Comment: Is [this](http://i.imgur.com/o5Ixxvr.png) the dialog that you call *the **old** one*? Could you upload a screenshoot of *the **new** one*?

Answer (score 9):

Try:

[`gnome-session-quit`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/man1/gnome-session-quit.1.html)

For more options:

```
gnome-session-quit --help
```

According to the manual, the following options are supported:

```
   --logout
          Prompt the user to confirm logout. This is the default behavior.

   --power-off
          Prompt the user to confirm system power off.

   --reboot
          Prompt the user to confirm system reboot.

   --force
          Ignore any inhibitors.

   --no-prompt
          End the session without user interaction. This only  works  with
          --logout.
```

Or looking at dbus-monitor, this is the command:

```
dbus-send --print-reply --dest="org.gnome.Shell" /org/gnome/SessionManager/EndSessionDialog org.gnome.SessionManager.EndSessionDialog.Open uint32:2 uint32:0 uint32:60 array:objpath:/org/gnome/SessionManager/EndSessionDialog
```

Answer (score 3):

To get that exact dialog, the only way is through dbus, since `gnome-sesion-quit` only shows the generic four-options dialog. I got this by looking at `dbus-monitor`. This is the command:

```
dbus-send --print-reply --dest="org.gnome.Shell" /org/gnome/SessionManager/EndSessionDialog org.gnome.SessionManager.EndSessionDialog.Open uint32:2 uint32:0 uint32:60 array:objpath:/org/gnome/SessionManager/EndSessionDialog
```