# How to create a "shutdown" unity launcher in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: unity, launcher, shutdown

How can I shutdown my laptop in one mouse click (or maybe two mouse clicks) from the unity launcher?

I've found a number of posts which describe how to create a unity launcher so you can shutdown your laptop with one mouse click - but these are for older versions of Unbuntu (16.04 etc). https://www.faqforge.com/linux/distributions/ubuntu/trigger-system-shutdown-ubuntu-unity-launcher/

Unfortunately these methods don't appear to work with the current version of Unity. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are we talking about "gnome"? Ubuntu 20.04 doesn't use "unity" anymore. And why don't you want to use the "power" icon on the top right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the shutdown command?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/283984/what-is-the-shutdown-command)

Comment: This (and answer from kanehekili) is EXTREMELY valuable for some circumstances. (It's helpful for 'regular' people who want / need to use a Gnome desktop in the easiest way possible.) See my comment at his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you are using a standard Ubuntu with "gnome" (not unity - which would make not much difference) here my proposal:
create a file like `/home/yourusername/.local/share/applications/exit.desktop`

Add the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Exec=systemctl poweroff
Name=My Exit
Comment=One Click Exit 
Icon=application-exit
NoDisplay=false
Categories=Utilities;System
```

Save it.
I had to change the "group" to "adm", by using the properties dialog:
[image]

Go to activities and search for "exit". Rightclick the icon and add it as "favorite". Now you have your icon (choose any you like) in the "dock"...

Comment: Thank you. This works brilliantly and is exactly what I was trying to do.

Comment: Then you should accept the answer. It honors the time one put into it ;-)

Comment: :-) Accepted the answer - Thanks.......BTW it's not that obvious to a new user that you are supposed to do this??

Comment: No sir. There might be tools around (I haven't checked) but it took me some time in the past to figure it out Glad I could share and it helped you. Especially Gnome incapacitates the user - one of the reasons why I'd prefer either KDE or XFCE. But it is a good place to start, as long as Gnome will provide a terminal ;-)

Comment: For me I had a system that was having graphics problems. Monitors going blank - so the top panel could not be seen or accessed. So (a) use gnome-extension to put the launcher (at least for now) on all monitors (ran  gnome-extensions prefs dash-to-dock@micxgx.gmail.com) and (b) create the button per kanehekili answer and add to the dash/launcher. Now I have a quick shutdown button on all screens/monitors - much better than yanking power every time the graphics go wonky. Thanks kanehekili!!!

Answer (score 0):

This is a very good question because shutting down Ubuntu 22.04 is a multi step process that I find very annoying.

Here is my solution for shutting down Ubuntu 22.04 running Gnome desktop in one mouse click.  You can also use this method to create launchers for any bash script you would like to launch from your Dash, Activities or Desktop.

1. `mkdir /home/$USER/shutdown`  (creates a folder called shutdown in home)
2. `nano /home/$USER/shutdown/shutdown.sh`  (creates a bash script in /shutdown)

Add the following to shutdown.sh

```
#! /bin/bash
shutdown now
```

and save shutdown.sh (in nano ctrl-o, enter, ctrl-x)

`#! /bin/bash` identifies the file as a bash script.
`shutdown now` is the bash command to shut down and "now" means now, not later.

3. `chmod 775 /home/$USER/shutdown/shutdown.sh`  (sets shutdown.sh permission to -rwxrwxr-x)
4. `nano /home/$USER/.local/share/applications/shutdown.desktop` (creates a .desktop file in /applications)

Add the following to shutdown.desktop

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec=/home/$USER/shutdown/shutdown.sh
StartupNotify=false
Name=Shutdown
Icon=/home/$USER/shutdown/shutdown.png
```

and save shutdown.desktop (in nano ctrl-o, enter, ctrl-x).  `Exec=` sets the path to the bash script containing the command to shutdown.  `Name=` sets the name of the command as found in Activities.  `Icon=` sets the path to the icon.

5. `chmod 775 /home/$USER/shutdown/shutdown.desktop` (sets shutdown.desktop permission to -rwxrwxr-x)
6. Save a suitable shutdown icon to /home/$USER/shutdown such as the following:

[image]

be sure to name the icon file identical to that given in `Icon=` statement in the .desktop file.  In this example the icon file is shutdown.png.

7. There are three ways you may now launch shutdown.sh

   a.  Press the Super key, type shutdown and then select the shutdown icon.

   b.  Press the Super key, type shutdown, right click the shutdown icon and select "Add to Favorites" to place the shutdown icon on the dash.

   c.  Copy the shutdown.desktop file to your desktop, right click and select "Allow Launching".

This is a rather lengthy explanation but it serves to demonstrate how to properly link a bash script to a graphical launcher.  A bash script can perform many useful task such as executing system commands, mounting drives, performing backups or launching applications.  The sky is the limit.